# Simplifying an algebraic integer expression

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have an expression where the variables are algebraic integers:
$p4 = \frac{p12 - p41 \cdot p21}{p22}$
p12 is degree 48 and p22 is most likely degree 48 too. p41 is degree 32 and p21 is degree 24. I am trying to avoid a geometric increase in degrees, p41*p21 is 32*24 = 768 and p12 - p41*p21 would be 48*768 = 36864 and then dividing this by p22 would give 48*36864 = degree 1769472 would is well beyond the capability of my computer (using GP-Pari)

How can this be simpified?  I strongly suspect that p42 is degree 192, but have no way to determine this unless I grind it out using the algdep command of GP-Pari which depends upon the accuracy of the digits (which will have to be around 20K) This would take several days to run.

Thanks for your suggestions.

- Randall

Comment: Perhaps you have more info that could reduce the degree. For example,
the fields generated individually by $p_{41}$ and $p_{21}$ could  intersect in a field of degree 16. and similar things.Also possibly a  a convenient automorphism (a Galois group element) might send your number $p_4$  to a number more amenable for computations.

Comment: What is p42? Is that the same as p4 in the first paragraph?

Comment: @Randall: Isn't your question essentially the same one as your question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24513/question-on-determining-the-minimal-polynomial-for-an-algebraic-quotient from 3 years ago?

How are your numbers $pxy$ given, by minimal polynomials or complex floats up to some precision?